# What happened to Husks after synthesis ending of Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect

If Shepard chooses synthesis ending (green one) - what actually happens to Husks? Are they dead or they become sane?

Comment: They got impaled and then sucked dry by the tech.  Pretty sure they're dead Jim.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Mac Walters, the creative director for the Mass Effect franchise from Bioware, they are not sentient anymore. He mentioned that in a video, in collaboration with Ars Technica, where he responded to unsolved mysteries of the Mass Effect Universe.

Specifically, the question he answered, which is related to yours, was:

> Do Reaper husks retain any of the personality of the converted individual, even if they have no control over their own actions?

And Mac's answer was:

> The answer to that is no. Reaper Husks are husks. You must kill them, do not hesitate if you see one, destroy [them].

This can be seen in the following video (see 1:01):